# AJAX partial not being rendered in Rails 3.2

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a registration system where, during the beta period, an invitation is required in order to register.  The user requests an invitation which then sends out an email with a token-embedded link back to the site. Ex:

```
`http://domain.com/register?invitation_token=V80vy3muGvjORfu2eA8SCg`
```

Rails then catches this token part of the URL in the routes file as this route:

```
`get 'register/:invitation_token', :controller => 'users', :action => 'new', as: 'accept'`
```

The purpose of this is to allow the system to display a registration form with the user's email pre-filled.  This way, we can track which of our beta users sent out the most invitations and had the most responses, etc., as a type of contest.

The URL gets routed to the **users#new** action which contains an **if statement** to determine the way the form is displayed.

***`users/new.html.erb`***

```
<% if @user.invitation %>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('#DialogPop').bPopup({loadUrl:'form', speed:'fast'});
    })(jQuery);
  </script>

<% else %>
  <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { isAjaxed: true } %>
<% end %>
```

If the user has an invitation token embedded in their URL, they are processed by **users#new** by calling a **popup (via `bPopup`)**, which then renders the users form partial (`users/_form`).

**PROBLEM:**

The popup form is displaying correctly, showing that the JS call is being processed correctly from within the `users/new.html.erb` file.  However, the contents of the `users/_form.html.erb` form are not being displayed.

What am I missing here???

**FYI** - The **`UsersController`** code is here...:

```
def new
@user = User.new(:invitation_token => params[:invitation_token])
@user.email = @user.invitation.email if @user.invitation
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {}
end
```

end

**NOTES:**  The information from the token is being passed along.  I can confirm that, when the form is being displayed, it does show the user's email address pre-filled in.

The popup functions from **`bPopup`** work flawlessly in other areas of the site, so I know it's not the JS code, with the exception of it being the URL call to **`'form'`**.

**EDIT** Adding the views...

`users/_form.html.erb`

```
<div id="new-form-holder">
  <%= isAjaxed = false unless (defined? isAjaxed) %>
  <%= form_for @user, remote: isAjaxed do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :invitation_token %>
  <%= f.text_field(:name, class: 'txtbx flt-left', style: 'width: 130px', placeholder: 'Name...') %>
  <%= f.text_field(:surname, class: 'txtbx flt-left', style: 'width: 170px', placeholder: 'Last Name...') %>
  <% if @user.invitation %>
    <%= f.text_field(:email, class: 'txtbx flt-left', style: 'width: 325px', placeholder: 'Email...', :disabled => true) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.text_field(:email, class: 'txtbx flt-left', style: 'width: 325px', placeholder: 'Email...') %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.password_field(:password, class: 'txtbx flt-left', style: 'width: 325px', placeholder: 'Password...') %>
  <%= f.password_field(:password_confirmation, class: 'txtbx flt-left', style: 'width: 325px', placeholder: 'Confirm password...') %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, image_submit_tag("img_blank.png", id: 'btnSubmit', class: 'btn-lrg flt-right', title: 'Submit'), class: 'btn-lrg flt-left submit-holder') %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, image_tag("img_blank.png", id: 'btnCancel', class: 'btn-lrg flt-right', title: 'Cancel'), class: 'btn-lrg flt-left submit-holder') %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you specified the div which has id `DialogPop` in your `new.html.erb` as you are appending the popup to that div

Comment: @Gowri - Yes, that is not the problem.  I had though of that as well, since I have the layout turned off for users#new.  I had added the `<div>` but that still doesn't resolve the issue of the content of the popup not displaying.  I will add the views to the question...